# How to center a text box field in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to put a text field in the center of me screen, yet everything I try, it just stays left align. How do I center this?

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>:
            <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try this class with your form-group: `justify-content-center`... Not sure what you've tried and haven't tried.

Comment: I have added 2 solutions, Please have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1)** You can use `class= "offset-md-4"` in bootstrap-4. It's not `col-md-offset-4`

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>:
      <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution 2)** You can use `class="mx-auto"` which is nothing but `margin-left:auto`

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-md-4 mx-auto">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>:
      <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using bootstrap so just simply put text-center class on input like this.

```
<div class="form-row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>:
        <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control text-center" />
    </div>
</div>
```

i tried your cod ants all center after putting the class.[image]

Comment: Interesting, this unfortunately didn't work for me

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using??

Comment: using version 4

Comment: <div class="form-row">
<div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>:
        <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control text-center" />
    </div>
</div>

then try this.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Image Souk</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="row">
<div class="offset-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>:
        <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control text-center" />
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">Put your form here</div>
```

`col-md-4` will take 4 columns out of 12.
`col-md--offset-4` will add one 4 column to both sides of this form.

Answer (score 0):

You needed to show your custom css. Perhaps there are rules that may override the rules suggested here.

Try like this:

```css
div.form-row div.col-md-4.col-md-offset-4 div.form-group {
  display: flex!important;
  justify-content: center!important; 
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>:
            <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```